# Blue horizontal lines when scanning with color

Tags: hardware-failure, scanner

I have an HP Scanjet G2410 flatbed scanner that was working perfectly until now.

When I try to scan something in color I get these large horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the picture. For some reason this only happens when I choose the Color option, the Grayscale and Black&White options work fine.

[image: blue lines]

Things I already tried:

- Replacing the cables
- Reinstalling the driver
- Trying to scan on a different PC

Is there anything I can do to fix it or is it broken beyond repair?

Comment: try a newer driver?

Comment: BTW, what is the connection type USB?